# String clustering (using trigrams?)

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, trigram

I have a list of strings, which I want to classify into groups. I then want to show on string from each groups.

Say my list looks like this:

- The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
- The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!!!!
- The brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
- Zing, dwarf jocks vex lymph
- dwarf jocks vex lymph123
- I love cookies

Then I want to show something like this (one string from each class):

- The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
- dwarf jocks vex lymph123
- I love cookies

I know trigrams are a very easy and useful solution for classifying strings into "strings which are similar" and "strings which are different". I'm also pretty sure they can be used for dividing a list of strings into classes, but I'm not sure how.

Can anyone here help me, or should I use something completely different?

I would much prefer a method which is simple and maintainable over high accuracy.

Comment: Your problem is **clustering**, not **classification** (edited tags and title)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nearly any clustering technique and simply select one representant from each cluster. One of the simpliest approaches would be to use k-medoids over the space of n-grams of your texts, and print out the cluster's centroids (as k-medoids requires centroids to be parts of the training set)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the criteria used for string clustering into groups. It is not clear from your question what is the grouping criteria. I can imagine any criteria:

- string length is into some range
- some letters presented (or not presented) into the string
- some words presented (or not presented) into the string
- string are close by some metric (e.g. Levenstein distance)
- string are close by sense
- and hundreds more..

Please exactly mention what is classification criteria in your case.